# I want to get subprocess's output while it is still running, but it is always block

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I have a c program which have stdin as input and stderr as output, i want to get it's output while it is still running,but it is always block,what should i do?

Here's the python code

```
i = 0
popen1 = subprocess.Popen(['./hello1'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
while i < 30:
    if popen1.poll() is None:
        popen1.stdin.write("ada\n")
        print("write line......")
        #print(popen1.stderr)
        for stderr_line in popen1.stderr:
            print(stderr_line, end="")
            sys.stderr.flush()
    i += 1
```

Here's the c code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i = 0;
    char str[20];
    while(i < 30){
        scanf("%s", str);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[0]);
        i++;
    }
    //while(1);
}
```

the result acually is

```
write line......
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=5 encoding='UTF-8'>
```

and then it blocks

Comment: But in python i have add input to stdin@ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're printing the reference to `stderr`. Also, you're flushing `sys.stderr`, but there's no data there, as you're printing to `sys.stdout`.

I would change the `for` loop to:

```
for stderr_line in popen1.stderr.read():
    print(stderr_line, end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: I'm sorry it still doesn't work,I think flush may not be it'reason.

Comment: Did you remove the `sys.stderr.flush()`?